# untagged traffic must become tagged traffic after passing through the bridge

Tags: linux-networking, vlan, bridge, network-design, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to achieve something simple.

I have a machine which has a single physical port `enp89s0`. this is connected to the native VLAN (`VLAN=1`).

I need to create VMs and place them on a separate `VLAN=166`.

In order to not specify the interface name of the machines in the systemd networkd, I have created a bridge and connect VMs there.

This bridge has as uplink an vlan interface `eth.166` which is connected to the main bridge.

the design would look like the following

```
              -------------               -------------
  enps890    |             |     eth.166 |              |
-------------|   br0       |-------------|    br166     | 
             |             |             |              |
             --------------               --------------
```

the VMs get connected to the `br166`.

The VMs do not tag the traffic so the traffic arrives untagged and the interface `eth.166` should tag it and pass it to the switch. My switch is configured with trunk port so I do not think is an issue of the switch. I've spent some time to it but I could not find the way.

Here my configuration

`br0.netdev`

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge

[Bridge]
VLANFiltering=yes
```

`br0.network`

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[Network]
VLAN=eth.166
```

`enps890.network`

```
[Match]
Name=enp89s0
[Network]
Bridge=br0
[BridgeVLAN]
VLAN=166
```

`br166.netdev`

```
[NetDev]
Name=br166
Kind=bridge

[Bridge]
VLANFiltering=yes
```

`br166.network`

```
[Match]
Name=br166

[Network]
DHCP=no
```

`eth.166.network`

```
[Match]
Name=eth.166

[Network]
Bridge=br166
DHCP=no

[BridgeVLAN]
VLAN=166
PVID=166
EgressUntagged=166
```

`eth.166.netdev`

```
[NetDev]
Name=eth.166
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=166
```

```
$ bridge vlan

port              vlan-id
enp89s0           1 PVID Egress Untagged
                  166
br0               1 PVID Egress Untagged
br166             1 PVID Egress Untagged
eth.166           1 Egress Untagged
                  166 PVID Egress Untagged
virbr0            1 PVID Egress Untagged
```

Comment: conceptually I do not understand whether we need to specify `[BridgeVLAN]` config for the interface `eth.166`. This interface is already a VLAN so it is required?

Comment: I don't get where "eth" is coming from. Your "eth.166" looks like a VLAN subinterface of some interface with the name "eth", but what is it and where is it defined, how Linux should create it if it supposed to be a virtual interface? You can't just take a name and use it out of nowhere. Maybe you meant to use [virtual ethernet pair device](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/veth.4.html)? One side of a pair can participate in one bridge, another side could be enslaved into another, or subinterfaced and put into bridge, it's up to you. Also, is that for `libvirt`?

Comment: Now I have fixed the issue. The issue was that br0 had to allow also vlan166 traffic. By the way Nikita you can call in Linux interfaces with whatever name you want and create them out of the blue. Up to your fantasy and your wishes. :-) I called eth.166. Now eveyrhing works. I'll post the correct config.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first use of systemd-networkd, but it clearly seemed to be the right tool for headless libvirt host, single physical interface, hosting guests on multiple VLANs.  I've been struggling with it, but just got it working, so will share what worked for me. Host and guests can use their respective network and Internet. Any host-guest traffic would have to traverse physical networks and router (external to host).

(1) physical INF: enp4s0f0
(2) VLANs:  f0.2 , f0.613
(2) Bridges for guest connection: brV2, brV613
Host getting DHCP address from untagged VLAN 1
Guest traffic is untaggged for the guest and tagged between host and upstream switch.  Guests use Bridge interface `brV2` or `brV613`.
Bridges intended only for guests, all the `<key>=no` entries under [Network] section avoids seeing a 'degraded' status from `networkctl list`.

For first entry into systemd-networkd, I found a drawing helpful.
[image: Config drawing - systemd.networkd with VLANs for libvirt guests]

```
/etc/systemd/network files:
```

> 10-enp4s0f0.network

```
[Match]
Name=enp4s0f0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
VLAN=f0.2
VLAN=f0.613

[DHCPv4]
UseDNS=no
```

> 28-vlan2.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=f0.2
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=2
```

> 28-vlan613.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=f0.613
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=613
```

> 30-vlan2.network

```
[Match]
Name=f0.2

[Network]
Bridge=brV2
```

> 30-vlan613.network

```
[Match]
Name=f0.613

[Network]
Bridge=brV613
```

> 30-br2.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=brV2
Kind=bridge
```

> 30-br613.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=brV613
Kind=bridge
```

> 30-V2-brNET.network

```
[Match]
Name=brV2

[Network]
DHCP=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
LLDP=no
EmitLLDP=no
IPv6AcceptRA=no
IPv6SendRA=no
```

> 30-V613-brNET.network

```
[Match]
Name=brV613

[Network]
DHCP=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
LLDP=no
EmitLLDP=no
IPv6AcceptRA=no
IPv6SendRA=no
```